# Problema en formulario con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy realizando un formulario en HTML y JavaScript, para poder sumar el IVA a un producto y utilizo la siguiente formula “ (subtotal * iva / 100) + subtotal “  al realizar la operación con variable establecidas dentro de JavaScript funciona correctamente, pero al  tomar los valores de los input no funciona, ya que me da un valor erróneo, y no sé qué estoy haciendo mal.

Por ejemplo, si agrego en sub total el valor 200 y en IVA 16 me da como resultados 32200, y el resultado correcto tiene que ser 232

```js
function res(){

    var sub = document.getElementById("subtotal").value; 
    var i = document.getElementById("iva").value;
  
    var final = (sub * i / 100) + sub;
    
    document.getElementById("subfinal").value = final;
  
     // alert("el resultado es: " +finx);
  }
```

```html
  <form>


        <h4>formulario </h4>

        <p>Sub-total</p>
        <input type="text" id="subtotal" class="for-control" placeholder="ingrese numero">


        <p>I.V.A (Ingrese el IVA)</p>
        <input type="text" id="iva" class="for-control" placeholder="ingrese numero">
        <button id="calcula" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="res()">Aceptar</button>

        <p>Sub-total final </p>
        <input type="text" id="subfinal" class="for-control">


    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El resultado le da erroneo porque la propiedad value es de tipo `String` entonces al obtenerlas en las variables `i` y `sub` tiene cadenas.

Realice el siguiente cambio en la asignacion utilizando el metodo `Number()` para forzar a que el valor sea tomado como numerico

```
var sub = Number(document.getElementById("subtotal").value); 
var i = Number(document.getElementById("iva").value);
```